# SVN Merging from branch to trunk

Tags: svn, merge

I have to merge the files of a particular release in the branch to trunk.
How can I do it.
Can anybody tell the steps to merge?
If I right click Tortoise SVN, merge->reintegrate a branch option, then I cant proceed.
Even if I select ignore anchestry option and try to merge, i cannot do it.
Anchestry error is coming. Help me out !!!

Answer (score 0):

In TortoiseSVN I find it easier to *always* use the merge option to [merge a range of revisions](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html).  I'm not sure what it's trying to do under the hood for the other options, but this one is clear enough.  You select the branch, select the revisions (even if it's all of the revisions for that branch), and select the target (trunk).  Those revisions from that branch get merged back in (after resolving conflicts, of course).